# Referencing text from one cell into an equation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have text in a cell (`A1`) that is also the name of a worksheet within my workbook. How do I go about referencing a specific cell on that sheet? I want it to look like the formula below without having to type in the text manually.

```
='Tab Name'!D16
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option1:**

```
='A1'!A1
```

should work.

**Option2:**

Click the cell that contains the data you want to link to, and then click Copy Button image on the Standard toolbar.
Click the cell you want to link from, and then click Paste Button image.
Click Paste Options Button image and then click Link Cells.

**Option3:**

```
=INDIRECT(‘$A$1′!A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `INDIRECT` function to turn a string into a reference.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!D16")
```